# Woocommerce email template customization

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic, templates, email

I have the latest version(3.3.4) of woocommerce and I'm  trying to customise the email templates that come with it. Tried following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ljPVbosVa8) tutorial, but the version I am using doesn't seem to contain the option to modify the HTML code from the template.

So my question is, how can the email templates be customized in the latest versions of woocommerce?

Comment: this customisation is always here in the last version. you find it in "Settings" -> "E-mails" and you click on an e-mail in the list.

Comment: @mmm I've tried that, but the only thing I get when I click on specific emails is just a page with fields to modify the subject and heading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an option in the WooCommerce settings that shows you how to override and edit the email templates: `WooCommerce -> Settings -> Emails`

From there, simply click on the email name or the cog/settings icon [image] to the right of the email template that you would like to modify and you will be presented with the following screen:

[image]

Highlighted in Red, is the section that refers to the emails HTML template.

You can click on the 'Copy file to theme' button and this will copy the email template file from:

`wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/emails/`

to your currently active themes folder as a template override:

`wp-content/themes/your-active-theme/woocommerce/emails/`

**Update:** This was caused by a plugin and was found when I asked OP to disable plugins to test in comments below

Comment: That's the problem, I am not getting that "HTML template" option either

Comment: Is your user an 'administrator'?

Comment: Yes the user is an 'Administrator'. So I have another Wordpress site on the same server with the same woocommerce version and the same theme installed, and this one is displaying HTML Template option. Only difference between them is just that in the second one I'm using the original theme while in the one where I have the issues I've the child theme activated. Not sure if that's the issue though

Comment: Will try switching from the child to the main

Comment: Yes, try switching the theme to the main theme, although it could possibly be a plugin causing the problem. Are your plugins the same on both sites and are they all up to date?

Comment: Thanks a lot, you were right. The problem was with some plugin I just deactivated most of the plugins and the HTML Templates option is back now. I will try finding out which plugin was causing the issue and maybe report to the respective support team

Comment: Great news, glad I could help :-)